# ClassCastException Runtime Error

Tags: runtime-error, classcastexception

I am trying to read website URLS, remove HTML tags, tokenize them, then put them for POS tagging.
It does all the above steps fine but breaks at the POS tagging. The error is coming from thePOSTagging class, anyone figured where I'm going wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
at POSTaggers.POSTagging.run(POSTagging.java:28)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
at Assignment2.Main.main(Main.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: I suspect that this is line 28 -- `for (ArrayList<String> a : inputtokens)`??

Comment: "_where I'm going wrong?_" -> `POSTagging.java:28)` At line 28 of that file you are trying to turn a String into an ArrayList.

Comment: I think you have your `for` loops FUBAR.

Comment: @HotLicks yeah, maybe the added class will help but it should be an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite straightforward, (you're casting a `String` to `ArrayList` in line 29 of `POSTagging.java`), but I can't see that happening.

What I do see is, you can't cast a `Object` array to a `String` array. You're doing:

```
taggers[0] = new OpenNLP((String[]) a.toArray());
```

Instead, use:

```
taggers[0] = new OpenNLP(a.toArray(new String[a.size()]));
```